# scala.util.Try does not wrap Exception when used with Future and Play WS

Tags: scala, exception, playframework-2.0, future

My understanding is that `scala.util.Try` wraps exceptions thrown any code inside the `Try { ... }` block.

Here is a simple example that wraps a NullPointerException.

```
object TryDemo extends App {

  import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}

  def doSomething(i: Int): String = {
    if (i > 50) {
      println("going to throw NullPointerException at index " + i)
      throw new NullPointerException("- Exception at index " + i)
    }
    else
      "some-result"
  }

  val t: Try[String] = Try {
    var x = 0
    while (x < 100) {
      doSomething(x)
      x += 1
    }
    "result-" + x
  }

  val result: Option[String] = t match {
    case Success(s) => println("success " + s); Some(s)
    case Failure(f) => println("failure " + f.getMessage()); None
  }
}
```

This gives the following output as excepted.

> going to throw NullPointerException at index 51
>
> failure - Exception at index 51

However, when I try to do the following (with an invalid URL to ensure that it fails every time)

```
import play.api.libs.ws._
val wsURL = "http://invalidurl:9000/something" 
val wsres: Try[Future[Response]] = Try {
  WS.url(wsURL).withRequestTimeout(200).withQueryString(("param", value)).get
}
```

Exceptions are thrown instead of getting an error that is wrapped inside a `Try`.
Can anyone please explain why it works in the first case and not in the second ?

```
[info]   java.net.ConnectException: http://invalidurl:9000/something
[info]   at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyConnectListener.operationComplete(NettyConnectListener.java:103)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListener(DefaultChannelFuture.java:427)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.addListener(DefaultChannelFuture.java:145)
[info]   at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.doConnect(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:1068)
[info]   at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.execute(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:890)
[info]   at com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient.executeRequest(AsyncHttpClient.java:520)
[info]   at play.api.libs.ws.WS$WSRequest.execute(WS.scala:177)
[info]   at play.api.libs.ws.WS$WSRequestHolder.get(WS.scala:386)
[info]   at controllers.geojson.GeoJsonTransfomer$$anonfun$9.apply(GeoJsonTransformer.scala:155)
[info]   at controllers.geojson.GeoJsonTransfomer$$anonfun$9.apply(GeoJsonTransformer.scala:155)
[info]   ...
[info]   Cause: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException:
[info]   at sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:127)
[info]   at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:640)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink.connect(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:108)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:70)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.handleDownstream(OneToOneEncoder.java:54)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec.handleDownstream(HttpClientCodec.java:97)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedWriteHandler.handleDownstream(ChunkedWriteHandler.java:109)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.connect(Channels.java:634)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.connect(AbstractChannel.java:207)
[info]   at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.connect(ClientBootstrap.java:229)
```

Comment: Wrapping a `Future` with `Try` makes no sense. A `Future` will hold on to all exceptions (in fact, `Future` *already* wraps `Try`). Are you sure this isn't the exception simply getting logged by Play WS?

Comment: @m-z I getting the exception in my tests. You make a good point about using the Try inside the Future. Thanks!